# How to fix Key Error: utid in the aiogram FSM

Tags: python, aiogram

When I try to pass data through FSM it gives me an Key Error.

```
class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    id = State()
    username = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands="fight",)
async def batle(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):   
    usrid = message.from_user.id
    usrname = message.from_user.first_name
    await FSMAdmin.id.set()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['utid']=message.from_user.id
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['username']=message.from_user.first_name
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        print(data)
    sx = InlineKeyboardButton('ok', callback_data='fight')
    baba = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True).add(sx)
    await message.reply("ok",reply_markup=baba)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='fight')
async def bytva(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMAdmin):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        print(data)
        usrid = data['utid']
        usrname = data['username']
```

In first function it prints info that were written, but in second one gives me an Key Error and prints enpty data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="fight",)
async def batle(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):   
    await FSMAdmin.id.set()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['utid']=message.from_user.id
        data['username']=message.from_user.first_name
        print(data)
    sx = InlineKeyboardButton('ok', callback_data='fight')
    baba = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True).add(sx)
    await message.reply("ok",reply_markup=baba)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda cb: cb.data == 'fight', state=FSMAdmin.id)
async def bytva(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMAdmin):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        print(data)
        usrid = data['utid']
        usrname = data['username']
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).